# El usuario ha de introducir una frase y el programa le dice si es palindroma

Tags: java

estoy experimentando un error (Unresolved compilation problem) en el siguiente codigo para verificar si una frase es palindroma. El programa pide al usuario entrar una frase y este le devuelve si es palindroma o no. Como puedo resolverlo? Muchas gracias

````
public static void main(String args[]) {
   }
       Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

       
       //dato de entrada
   error   System.out.println("Introduce una frase: ");
       String frase= sc.nextLine();

       //eliminar 
   public static boolean esPalindromo(String frase) {
               // Convertir a minúscula y quitar espacios " ", puntos "." y comas ","
               // También remplazar palabras con acento p.ej. í => i
       
               frase = frase.toLowerCase().replace("á", "a").replace("é", "e").replace("í", "i").replace("ó", "o")
                       .replace("ú", "u").replace(" ", "").replace(".", "").replace(",", "");
               
                   
               for (int x=frase.length()-1;x>=0;x--) {
                   String fraseReves= fraseReves+frase.charAt(x);
                           
                       }
                       System.out.println(frase);
   error                   System.out.println(fraseReves);
                       
   error                   if(frase.equalsIgnoreCase(fraseReves)) {
                           System.out.println("Es un palindromo");
                       }else
                           System.out.println("No es un palindromo");
                       return false;
                       
       }

   } ```
````

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Por favor edita tu pregunta (enlace Editar justo debajo) y cuéntanos: ¿cuál es el error en tu programa? No lo indicaste

Comment: Hola @Emmy, edita tu pregunta y escribe las líneas de error que muestra tu compilador

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask] y 
[mre] y 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Answer (score 0):

Según el código que comparte, existen varios errores, te los describo:

1. tu metodo **main** no contiene ninguna línea de código dentro, al ejecutar tu programa no muestra nada.
2. las lineas de código siguientes están fuera de cualquier método, obvio que te va mostrar error.

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
       //dato de entrada
       System.out.println("Introduce una frase: ");
       String frase= sc.nextLine();
       //eliminar
```

3. Tu método **esPalindromo** es un booleano, pero siempre va retornar falso debido a que en ninguna linea de tu código se cambia el valor; otro detalle es que en tu método **main** tienes que llamar a tu método **esPalindromo**

Te comparto tu código corregido que muestra el resultado que estas consultando, copia los 2 métodos dentro de una clase

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
       Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("Introduce una frase: ");
       String frase= sc.nextLine();
        esPalindromo(frase);
       
   }
   static void esPalindromo(String frase) {
       // Convertir a minúscula y quitar espacios " ", puntos "." y comas ","
       // También remplazar palabras con acento p.ej. í => i
       String fraseReves="";
       frase = frase.toLowerCase().replace("á", "a").replace("é", "e").replace("í", "i").replace("ó", "o")
               .replace("ú", "u").replace(" ", "").replace(".", "").replace(",", "");               

       for (int x=frase.length()-1;x>=0;x--) {
           fraseReves= fraseReves+frase.charAt(x);                           
        }
       System.out.println("La frase es: "+frase);
       System.out.println("La frase reversa es: "+fraseReves);

       if(frase.equalsIgnoreCase(fraseReves)) 
           System.out.println("Es un palindromo");
       else
           System.out.println("No es un palindromo");               
    }
```